# 'RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument' after ifup ethX

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet, ifconfig

On a device with Debian 10, I want to make a permanent change to the IP via modifying ***/etc/network/interfaces*** . Hence, I modify it as follows :

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0
    #iface eth0 inet dhcp
    iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.109.11
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.109.254
```

and after that I perform the following :

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

but at this point it returns the following error :

```
root@var-som-mx6:~# ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0 --verbose
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

ifup: configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/hostapd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/sbin/ip addr add 192.168.109.12/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.109.255      dev eth0 label eth0
/sbin/ip link set dev eth0   up
 /sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.109.254  dev eth0 onlink 
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
ifup: failed to bring up eth0
```

***ifconfig*** tells me the following :

```
root@var-som-mx6:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.109.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.109.255
        inet6 fe80::fadc:7aff:fe3e:8dbb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f8:dc:7a:3e:8d:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 35999  bytes 8217478 (7.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5137  bytes 1559379 (1.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2837  bytes 258173 (252.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2837  bytes 258173 (252.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setting the gateway address to be the same as the broadcast address is a bit strange choice. While it might work, I think it would make your network less efficient by increasing the amount of broadcast traffic.

Comment: You are actually right, it's a mistake since I was actually trying to use the .254. I will edit my question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ifdown** and **ifup** seem to be not the best way to operate on network interfaces due to lots of pseudo-errors with RTNETLINK (Linux routing socket) that will go away only via system reboot, which may not be ideal.

IMHO, main way to handle this is via **ifconfig** commands (please also consider that *ifconfig* is deprecated and is replaced by the *ip* command) :

> ```
> root@var-som-mx6:~# ifconfig eth0 down
> ** now, update /etc/network/interfaces.. **
> root@var-som-mx6:~# ifconfig eth0 up 192.168.109.11 netmask 255.255.255.0
> root@var-som-mx6:~# route add default gw 192.168.109.254
> ```

Note that you should update the */etc/network/interfaces* **after** the *ifconfig eth0 down*

BTW, if you got your reasons to use **ifdown** and **ifup**, you can solve this as following :

> ```
> root@var-som-mx6:~# ifdown --force eth0
> ** now, update /etc/network/interfaces.. **
> root@var-som-mx6:~# ifup --force eth0
> root@var-som-mx6:~# route add default gw 192.168.109.254
> ```

where --force will force configuration or deconfiguration of the interface ([source](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/ifdown.8.en.html)), in particular :

> The program keeps records of whether network interfaces are up or down. Under exceptional circumstances these records can become inconsistent with the real states of the interfaces. For example, an interface that was brought up using ifup and later deconfigured using ifconfig will still be recorded as up. To fix this you can use the --force option to force ifup or ifdown to run configuration or deconfiguration commands despite what it considers the current state of the interface to be.

If you also prefer to have all in one command line, the correct one-liner is the following :

> ```
> root@var-som-mx6:~# ifdown eth0 --force && ip addr flush dev eth0 && route add default gw 192.168.109.254 && ifup eth0 --force
> ```

where *ip addr flush dev eth0* is crucial.

This solutions solve also the "*RTNETLINK answers: File exists*" error.

Comment: To avoid this kind of issue, do ifdown first, then change the configuration then do ifup. Don't change the configuration before ifdown.

Comment: It actually worked, thanks @A.B. I will integrate your answer with mine.